# Access Mac Camera from Pycharm

Tags: macos, pycharm

I want to capture video using Mac camera. I'm using the opencv4.0.0 library for capturing and writing the video. Using the terminal:

```
python main.py
```

I can access to Mac camera, but when I execute the same command with the Pycharm editor, I have the following problem:

[image: intrerrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT]

This is probably because I should enable Pycharm access to the camera from the Security & Privacy - > Privacy -> Camera. I searched through google, and I couldn't figure out how I can add the PyCharm to the Privacy section. Do you have any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
from cv2 import VideoCapture, imshow, waitKey, destroyAllWindows,   
                VideoWriter, VideoWriter_fourcc

cap = VideoCapture(0)
video_codec = VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
output = VideoWriter("usb_webcam.avi", video_codec, 20.0, (640, 480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    imshow(winname="frame", mat=frame)
    output.write(image=frame)
    if waitKey(delay=20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
output.release()
destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Sounds like a known problem https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219288

Answer (score 1):

None of the proposed solutions worked for me. 
After some research, a comment by Lev Sokolov on [jetbrains issues section](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-37467#focus=streamItem-27-3652849.0-0) helped me solve the problem.

1. Open Xcode
2. File > New Project
3. Choose macOS App
4. Fill the info of the project:

   - Product Name: `pycharm`
   - Organization Identifier: `com.jetbrains`
   - Make sure Bundle identifier you get is: `com.jetbrains.pycharm`
   - Language: `Swift`
   - User Interface: `Storyboard`
5. In the new project edit `Info.plist` file by adding new Property `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` with some description `Give me my camera access!`
6. In `AppDelegate.swift` file in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching` function insert the following code requesting camera access:

   `import AVKit
    ...
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
           // Insert code here to initialize your application
           AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { _ in }
    }`
7. Run the application.
8. When prompted to allow camera access to `pycharm` application, allow it (from this moment you will also see the pycharm app in the Camera tab in the mac  Security&Privacy)
9. Exit the Xcode, restart the PyCharm
10. Enjoy your camera access from PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

There is an official way to enable this in PyCharm configuration. Edit the file

```
/Applications/PyCharm\ CE.app/Contents/Info.plist
```

Add a new key and string pair in dict. Example:

```
 <key>Privacy - Camera Usage</key> 
 <string>PyCharm Project name</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled quite a bit to figure out this issue, finally I found one solution to access camera from PyCharm on mac is to run your .py file with terminal.

Take these steps:

- For an example, I have a file named as main.py. This basically initialize the camera and reads the frame and then opens up in a separate window [image]
- Right click on main.py(in the project explorer) and select open in terminal [image]
- In the terminal window of pyCharm IDE, type this command **python main.py** (python **and your file name**) [image]

You will get a prompt window to allow access to your camera,please press Ok and this will enable your camera module.

Answer (score 0):

all u have to do :

1- go to applications

2- drag the pycharm into the terminal

3- put cd before the absolute path

4- cd Contents

5- nano Info.plist

6- paste:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>uses camera to see vision targets</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

7- press ctrl+c then enter

8- press ctrl+x to exit